# Logistic regression in SQL

Tags: sql-server, r, logistic-regression

Can someone give me pointers on any resources/implementation ideas for logistic regression on core SQL server. I am aware of R algorithms but looking for SQL implementations.

Comment: I highly doubt such a thing is possible. Youre better off searching out large-scale logistic regression tools like Vowpal Wabbit.

Comment: I did some research online and also heard back from other experts in the field. While R/Python are the best engines for statistical algorithms, but if one wants to try it with SQL, the CLR (write code in C# and deploy it within SQL as assembly) is one approach. Not sure if it would perform any better than R/Python though.